# Concealing long paths in variables in Bash

Tags: bash

I have to move files from one folder to another but they reside in totally different paths. The destination path is so long and complicated that I am not able to remember it. Is there any way to go first to destination directory then store the path in some variable lets suppose X and then go to source directory and write a command like that:

```
 mv * $X
```

Comment: you know you can simply drag a directory over the terminal window to use it?

Comment: No I did not know about that, thank you :).

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
cd /your/long/path
X=$(pwd)
```

The command `pwd` prints the current directory; with the command `X=$(pwd)` you are storing the output of the command in the variable(1) `X` (no spaces around the `=`!)

```
cd /the/other/dir/
mv * "$X"
```

Now you are *using* the value of the variable `X`, using `$X` (read $ as "the value of"). The `"` that are around the `$X` are needed if the directory name contains spaces or other special characters.

If you are unsure about what is in X, you can check its content with

```
echo "$X"
```

---

(1) in the `bash` (and other) shells they are called *parameters*. See for example [here for a simple tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial), or [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-parameters/).

Comment: Is there any restriction on number of variables and their names ?

Comment: No restriction on (reasonable) number, and few on the name. Stick with letters, numbers (but don't start with a number) and underscores and you are safe. Note that `x` and `X` are different --- the shell is case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your shell is bash, you can use

```
pushd /your/long/directory
popd
mv ./* "$OLDPWD"
```

$OLDPWD is set by bash when you change directories.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I've tried to create a more elaborate version of `X=$(pwd)` and `mv * $X`. The result was something that I call a "bashPortalGun". Here it is:

https://github.com/tyukiand/bashPortalGun

These scripts transform your shell prompt into something like this:

```
me@host [orange -> there] here$
```

and allow you to do everything you would expect from a "portal gun", applied to the
context of the bash-shell:

```
me@host ~$ cd /very/long/path
me@host /very/long/path$ pOrange # create orange portal
me@host [orange -> .portal.closed] /very/long/path$ cd /some/other/directory
me@host /some/other/directory$ pBlue # create blue portal
me@host [blue -> path] /some/other/directory$ mv file.txt [orange] # move stuff through portal
```

In my experience, it makes the usage of `mv` and `cd` more comfortable, especially when working with multiple shells. Maybe you find it useful, maybe you just consider it cool to have a portal gun in your bash :)

Motivated test subjects are welcome. Constructive feedback will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are now in the directory with files you want to move, use

```
cd target_dir
cd -
```

to store your target_dir in `$OLDPWD` variable, and move back to your original directory.

Now, you may use

```
mv * "$OLDPWD"
```

to move your files to your target directory.

---

**Notes:**

`$PWD`(**P**rint **W**orking **D**irectory) always remebers current working directory.

And `$OLDPWD` always remebers last working directory.

By the way, use TAB key to auto-complete your path when typing your path.

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps easier to just create temporary symbolic links instead of variables.

It's also not all that "un-handy" to use "tab" auto-completion/suggestions. But may depend on one's individual .bashrc, I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Why do not use variables for src and dest-Path?
Here a little script:

```
IFS='
'
SRC="/PATH/TO/SOURCE-PATH"
DST="/PATH/TO/DEST-PATH"
for i in `ls $SRC` 
do
mv $SRC/$i $DST/.
done
```

the IFS is important, if you have filenames with spaces. Without IFS the for-loop do in some environments a line-break on this spaces. ([SOURCE](http://infofreund.de/bash-script-for-loop-through-files/))

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#ls)! This could all be done with a single command: `mv -t /PATH/TO/DEST-PATH /PATH/TO/SOURCE-PATH/*`.